# What sample application demonstrates best practices for MVC structure in a Google App Engine/Python app?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, google-app-engine, design-patterns, architecture

Although I know the Python language, I've never built a significant web app containing a large number of classes.

Now that I am contemplating doing so, I am questioning how best to structure the code in an organized way as I would normally do in a Java application.

Are there any sample Python web apps for App Engine that provide a good example of large-scale code structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend checking out [Bloggart](https://github.com/Arachnid/bloggart) and [rietveld](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/).

For more, [here's a list of App Engine samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/), [a big list of open-source App Engine projects](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/web/google-app-engine-open-source-projects?pli=1), and [another one](http://www.uptosomething.in/weblog/?page_id=355).

Comment: imho, Bloggart is not easy to digest for a first experience user and its code organization does not really shine; it's still a fantastic blog engine even so.

Answer (score 2):

[rietveld](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/), by Guido van Rossum (Python creator) is a Django app built on GAE and is a good one to check out.